# Using Substitution to Solve a 1st Order Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

Solve $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x^2 + y^2}{xy}$ for $y(1) = 2$

I began by simplifying such that: $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{x}{y} - \frac {y}{x}$

Then, I set $v = \frac {y}{x}$

Therefore: $y = xv$ and $y'$ = $v$ + $xv'$

Substituting back: $v + xv' = \frac{x}{xv} - \frac{xv}{x}$

or $v + xv' = \frac{1}{v} - v$

To continue, should $x$ be divided from both sides to allow for use of an integrating factor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To continue with your method then

( You have a sign mistake )
$$v + xv' = 1/v \color{red}{+} v$$
$$v'vx=1$$

It's separable
$$\int vdv=\int \frac {dx}x$$
$$v^2=2 \ln  |x|+C$$
Substitute back $v=\frac y x$

---

***Another approach***

$$y'xy=x^2+y^2$$
Note that 
$$(y^2)'=2yy'$$
$$\frac x2(y^2)'=x^2+y^2$$
Substitute $y^2=z$
$$\frac x2z'=x^2+z$$
It's a first order differential equation
$$z'-\frac 2xz=2x$$
Multiply by $x^2$
$$z'x^2-2xz=2x^3$$
Divide by $x^4$
$$\left(\frac z {x^2}\right )'=\frac 2x$$
Integrate
$$\left(\frac z {x^2}\right )=2 \ln |x|+K$$
$$z=2 x^2\ln |x|+Kx^2$$
$$z(1)=y^2(1)=4 \implies K=z=4$$
$$\boxed {y(x)=\pm |x|\sqrt {2\ln |x|+4}}$$